# cant figure out why my application doesn't validate inputs properly

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import re

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='customer_data_error.log', level=logging.ERROR)

# Define a Customer class to represent a customer
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, first_name, surname, dob, address, postcode, email, phone):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.surname = surname
        self.dob = dob
        self.address = address
        self.postcode = postcode
        self.email = email
        self.phone = phone

# Define a Data class to manage the customer data
class CustomerData:
    def __init__(self, csv_file):
        self.filename = "customers.csv"
        self.customers = []
        self.csv_file = csv_file

    # Load customer data from a CSV file
    def load_data(self):
        try:
            with open(self.filename, 'r') as file:
                reader = csv.reader(file)
                next(reader)  # skip header row
                for row in reader:
                    first_name, surname, dob_str, address, postcode, email, phone = row
                    dob = datetime.strptime(dob_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                    customer = Customer(first_name, surname, dob, address, postcode, email, phone)
                    self.add_customer(customer)
        except FileNotFoundError as e:
            logging.error(str(e))

    # Add a new customer to the data
    def add_customer(self, customer):
        self.customers.append(customer)

    # Update an existing customer in the data
    def update_customer(self, first_name, surname, email, phone, address, postcode):
        for customer in self.customers:
            if customer.first_name == first_name and customer.surname == surname:
                customer.email = email
                customer.phone = phone
                customer.address = address
                customer.postcode = postcode
                break
        else:
            logging.error(f'Customer not found: {first_name} {surname}')
            return

    # Delete a customer from the data
    def delete_customer(self, first_name, surname):
        for customer in self.customers:
            if customer.first_name == first_name and customer.surname == surname:
                confirm = input(
                    f'Are you sure you want to delete {customer.first_name} {customer.surname} from the data? (y/n): ')
                if confirm.lower() == 'y':
                    self.customers.remove(customer)
                    print('Customer deleted.')
                else:
                    print('Deletion cancelled.')
                break
        else:
           logging.error(f'Customer not found: {first_name} {surname}')

    # Search for a customer in the data by first name and surname
    def search_customer(self, first_name, surname):
        for customer in self.customers:
            if customer.first_name == first_name and customer.surname == surname:
                print(f'{customer.first_name} {customer.surname}\n'
                      f'DOB: {customer.dob}\n'
                      f'Address: {customer.address}, {customer.postcode}\n'
                      f'Email: {customer.email}\n'
                      f'Phone: {customer.phone}\n')
                break
        else:
            logging.error(f'Customer not found: {first_name} {surname}')

    # Save customer data to a CSV file
    def save_data(self):
        with open(self.csv_file, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(['first_name', 'surname', 'dob', 'address', 'postcode', 'email', 'phone'])
            for customer in self.customers:
                writer.writerow([customer.first_name, customer.surname, customer.dob,
                                 customer.address, customer.postcode, customer.email, customer.phone])

        # validation
        def check(email):
            regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
            if (re.search(regex, email)):
                print("Valid Email")
                return (email)
            else:
                print("Invalid Email")
                check(input("enter email:"))

        def phone_number(s):
            regex = re.compile(r"^(?:\+44|0)7\d{9}$")
            return regex.match(s)

        def name_validation(_name):
            return _name.isalpha()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = CustomerData('customers.csv')
    data.load_data()
    # Main loop
    while True:
        print('1. Add customer')
        print('2. List customers')
        print('3. Update customer')
        print('4. Delete customer')
        print('5. Search customer')
        print('6. Save and exit')
        choice = input('Enter your choice: ')

        # Switch function
        if choice == '1':
            first_name = input('Enter first name: ')
            surname = input('Enter surname: ')
            dob = input('Enter date of birth (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
            address = input('Enter address: ')
            postcode = input('Enter postcode: ')
            email = input('Enter email: ')
            phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
            customer = Customer(first_name, surname, dob, address, postcode, email, phone)
            data.add_customer(customer)
            print('Customer added.')
        elif choice == '2':
            for i, customer in enumerate(data.customers, start=1):
                print(f'{i}. {customer.first_name} {customer.surname}')
        elif choice == '3':
            first_name = input('Enter first name: ')
            surname = input('Enter surname: ')
            email = input('Enter email: ')
            phone = input('Enter phone number: ')
            address = input('Enter address: ')
            postcode = input('Enter postcode: ')
            data.update_customer(first_name, surname, email, phone, address, postcode)
            print('Customer updated.')
        elif choice == '4':
            first_name = input('Enter first name: ')
            surname = input('Enter surname: ')
            data.delete_customer(first_name, surname)
            print('Customer deleted.')
        elif choice == '5':
            first_name = input('Enter first name: ')
            surname = input('Enter surname: ')
            data.search_customer(first_name, surname)
        elif choice == '6':
            # Ask user for confirmation
            confirm = input('Are you sure you want to save and exit? (y/n): ')
            if confirm.lower() == 'y':
                data.save_data()
                print('Data saved.')
                break
        else:
            print('Invalid choice.')
```

im trying to add validation for my input so people cant input false data that's not allowed for certain things, like for names you cant use numbers or symbols etc. what I've added doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why. I'm new to python so not 100% on what im doing wrong or what needs to be done.

Comment: What is currently going wrong?